# Creating an entry point in a C# DLL to call from WIX

Tags: c#, dll, wix, entry-point

I am trying to find a way to create an entry point for my C# DLL. I am aware of how to call other DLL's in C# but cannot find how to create one. I need this in order to call it in my WiX installer as a customer action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is mark your method up with the CustomAction attribute.

So:

```
[CustomAction] 
public static ActionResult MyThing(Session session) 
{ 
  // do your  stuff...
  return ActionResult.Success; 
}
```

As you are already calling other C# assemblies from WiX, it sounds like you have WiX 3.0, which supports the managed wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create entry points in dlls using C#, the only way to create managed dll with custom entry points is to use Managed C++ (CLI).

You can use the [DTF (Deployment Tools Foundation)](http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/09/03/WiXAndDTFIntroduction.aspx) to create managed custom actions that can be called from WIX.

Comment: shameless-plug: http://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports g - Serious, though, I hear that way too often. C++/CLI is a big can of worms in itself..